# I cant select only one active object in blender

Tags: selection-tools, select

Whenever I just select one object in object mode, and then go into edit mode, it has multiple active objects that i can edit, and then when i try to select one face, line, or vertex, it selects multiple, although in the bottom menu it says im only selecting one.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your objects are probably linked to each other, so when you change one of them you change the others too

[image]

If you select one  of those objects you should see in the object data tab that near the mesh name there is a 2 or another number: that means that there are 2 (or more) objects that share that mesh.

To solve it, click on that "2" button or in the 3d viewport choose Object>Relations>Make Single User> Object and Data

[image]

Comment: Thanks! it worked :3